# Sorting a list of list by key in R

Tags: r, list, sorting, key

I have the following list:

```
myList <- list(list(a = 1,b = 1:5,x = 2),
               list(a = 7,b = 9.1,x = 3),
               list(a=-1, b = 0.2, x = 1))
```

And I would like to sort my elements in this list by criterion "x".
I am at loss on how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
myList[order(sapply(myList, "[[", "x"))]
```

will do the trick

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] -1

[[1]]$b
[1] 0.2

[[1]]$x
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] 1

[[2]]$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]$x
[1] 2


[[3]]
[[3]]$a
[1] 7

[[3]]$b
[1] 9.1

[[3]]$x
[1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks Sven, it works perfectly! I didn't know that trick sapply(myList,"[[","x")

Comment: I suspect calling `[[` is faster, but you could also use the slightly less strange looking `mapply(get, 'x', myList)`.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde This could also be done with `sapply(myList, get, x = 'x')`.